# Chart.js - disable tooltip when cursor moves outside the main canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a line chart and I set up my tooltip like this

```
options: {
        tooltips:{
            mode: 'x',
          intersect: false,
          callbacks: {
            footer: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return 'some text'
            }
          }
        },    
    }
```

It works fine. The problem I have is that when I move my cursor to the x-axis ticks, which are outside the main plot/canvas, the tooltips stills appear. I've tried to set `intersect: true` but then the tooltip only shows up when I hover directly over the points. Ideally I want the tooltips to appear whenever I hover over the vertical gridlines (happens when `intersect:false`), but to not appear when my cursor moves outside of the main canvas. Is it possible?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dqdqdq/yp47oL9t/47/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onHover` callback in the options to check if the mouse is in the `chartArea` if so set the tooltip to enabled else disable the tooltip.

You might want to check also if the value you are setting is already the correct value since it will save a lot of unesesarry updates

Example (V2):

```js
const updateTooltipShow = (chart, enabled) => {
  chart.options.tooltips.enabled = enabled;
  chart.update();
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'line',

  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
      },

    ]
  },
  options: {
    onHover: function(e, activeElements) {
      const {
        bottom,
        top,
        right,
        left
      } = this.chartArea;
      if (e.x >= left && e.x <= right && e.y <= bottom && e.y >= top) {
        updateTooltipShow(this, true)
      } else {
        updateTooltipShow(this, false)
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x',
      intersect: false,
      callbacks: {
        footer: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return 'some text'
        }
      }
    },
  }

});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
```

Example (V3):

```js
const updateTooltipShow = (chart, enabled) => {
  chart.options.plugins.tooltip.enabled = enabled;
  chart.update();
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'line',

  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
      },

    ]
  },
  options: {
    onHover: (e, activeElements, chart) => {
      const {
        bottom,
        top,
        right,
        left
      } = chart.chartArea;
      if (e.x >= left && e.x <= right && e.y <= bottom && e.y >= top) {
        updateTooltipShow(chart, true)
      } else {
        updateTooltipShow(chart, false)
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'x',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
          footer: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return 'some text'
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple plugin for hiding the caption when you move your cursor out of the main canvas:

```
plugins: [{
    id: "toolbarHider",
    afterEvent: (chart: any, evt: any, opts: any) => {
        const { left, right, bottom, top } = chart.chartArea;
        const e = evt.event;
        const status = e.x >= left && e.x <= right && e.y <= bottom && e.y >= top;
        if (status !== chart.options.plugins.tooltip.enabled) {
            chart.options.plugins.tooltip.enabled = status;
            chart.update();
        }
    }
}]
```

More about [Chart.js plugins](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html).